# twitter4j error when search twitter

Tags: android, twitter4j

**[EDIT]**
I am trying to search some tweets from twitter using twitter4j version 4.0.4 as library. This is my method

```
public void processAll(View view){
    Log.d("click","OKE");
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxxx")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxx")
            .setOAuthAccessToken("7xxxxL")
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxxxx");
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
    Log.d("connected","OKE");

    try {
        Query query = new Query("handsome");
        Log.d("TEST","OKE");
        QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
        List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
        for (Status tweet : tweets) {
            Log.d("RESULT","@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText());
        }
    }
    catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("RESULT","Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
        return;
    }

}
```

But my app stopped when this method is called.

```
 at com.fajarainul.coconut_dev.titikota.SetTimeActivity.processAll(SetTimeActivity.java:68)
```

references to

```
    QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
```

here my full logcat

```
09-01 21:17:52.862  12562-12562/com.fajarainul.coconut_dev.titikota E/Spinner﹕ setPopupBackgroundDrawable: incompatible spinner mode; ignoring...
09-01 21:17:53.947  12562-12562/com.fajarainul.coconut_dev.titikota E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.fajarainul.coconut_dev.titikota, PID: 12562
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3834)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4461)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18523)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3829)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4461)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18523)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1148)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:251)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:229)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
            at twitter4j.HttpResponseImpl.<init>(HttpResponseImpl.java:35)
            at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:142)
            at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:53)
            at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.get(HttpClientBase.java:71)
            at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1556)
            at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.search(TwitterImpl.java:247)
            at com.fajarainul.coconut_dev.titikota.SetTimeActivity.processAll(SetTimeActivity.java:70)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3829)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4461)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18523)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you got internet permissions in your manifest?

Comment: yes, I have.. but still does not work...

Comment: Can you please copy your full log stacktrace into your question instead of providing images

Comment: sory my bad, i have edited my question.. thanks.. that is my error logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are throwing a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` which means you are attempting to run network code (i.e. running a search via the twitter API) on the applications main thread.

You will need to move this code into a background thread using something like an `AsyncTask` (see [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)) for it to work.

I would suggest reading the docs and also the responses to the previous question on SO: [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)